# Summernote and customize "magic pen" (style) tool

Tags: plugins, wysiwyg, summernote

I am using [summernote](https://summernote.or) in my project and i want customize `style` button with "magic pen" icon. In this button you can set h1-h6 or quotes, code(pre tag)....

There is my summernote toolbar settings:

```
                    toolbar: [                           
                        ['style', ['style']],                          
                        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                        ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
                        ['help', ['help']]
                    ]
```

first `style` setting is for "magic pen" button (first from left on toolbar), second `style` is for bold italic... button group (second from left on toolbar).

So is there some possibility customize first `style` button with "magic pen" icon?

I need remove some options from there... h1, h5, quotes, code...

On internet i was find some solutions which not work:

StyleTags options (not toolbar):

```
                     styleTags: 
                         ['p', 'blockquote', 'pre']
```

Or specify first 'style':

```
                    toolbar: [                           
                        ['style', ['blockquote', 'pre']],
```

but without success can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got sorted with this but had this issue today, Summernote documentation wouldn't be the best but this worked for me and might help someone else out in the future.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea[data-content~=summernote-content]').summernote({
    height: 400,
    toolbar: [
          ['style', ['style']],
          ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['help', ['help']]
        ],
        styleTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5'],
  });
});
```

So you just define the style as normal in the toolbar tags but then below it you specify the actual attributes you wish to show.